# Android Studio Hedgehog 2023.1.1 Patch 1 - compilation errors and long build times

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Everytime I change kotlin code and click "Run" the compiler first throws a random compilation error and build stops. Clicking on "Run" again works fine and after very long build times will run the app. It kind of feels like the IDE always does clean rebuild on 2nd run.

This was not the case with Android Studio Giraffe. I didn't find any issues about this so decided to ask a question first. Is anyone experiencing similar problems with latest version of Android Studio Hedgehog?

```
Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-231.9392.1.2311.11255304, built on December 26, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.7+0-17.0.7b1000.6-10550314 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 14.2
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 12
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    debugger.new.tool.window.layout=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    ide.instant.shutdown=false
    ide.experimental.ui=true

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.margush.ConstructionPaper (1.13)
```

and my project build.gradle file:

```
id("com.android.application") version "8.2.1" apply false
id("com.android.library") version "8.2.1" apply false
id("com.android.test") version "8.2.1" apply false
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.21" apply false
id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.21-1.0.16" apply false
```

I saw kotlin version 1.9.22 was released with corresponding version for ksp but I can't try it because compose compiler 1.5.7 doesn't support that version of kotlin yet.